# I have problem with transactional email -magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Can anyone help me to send transactional email through the custom module and its editable with transactional email in backend template?

I want to send transactional email but it's not working.

I have created below function to send email from transactional email.

```
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        $receverEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('ultimo/education_email/education_sendemail');
        $custom_template=Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/custom_template');
        $custom_identity=Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/custom_identity');

         Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
        ->sendTransactional(
            $custom_template,
            array('name' => $fromName,'email' => $fromEmail),  
            $receverEmail,
            null,
            array('name' => $params['person-name'],'email' => $params['person-email'],'school_name' => $params['school-name'],'school_address' => $params['school-address']));

        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();  

    $sender = array( 
      'name'  =>  $fromName,
      'email' =>  $fromEmail
    );

    $storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();

    $receverEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('ultimo/education_email/education_sendemail', $storeId);

    $custom_template = Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/custom_template', $storeId);

    $custom_identity = Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/account_share/custom_identity',$storeId);


    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');  

    $translate->setTranslateInline(false); 

    $data = array(
        'name' => $params['person-name'],
        'email' => $params['person-email'],
        'school_name' => $params['school-name'],
        'school_address' => $params['school-address']
    );

    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional($custom_template, $sender, $receverEmail, $storeName, array('data'=>  $data), $storeId);

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
```